# mysql group by returning incorrect result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have two tables (timesheet and tasks) each contains an hour value column "allocated hours" and "actual hours" of which I am trying to get the sum of both of these values.
also the timesheet table contains a integer value for "staff_id" which corresponds to the "assigned_to" in the task table

the task table contains:

```
task_id INT(11)
assigned_to INT(11)
date_start DATE
hrs DECIMAL (10,0)
```

the timesheet table contains:

```
timesheet_id (int)
name varchar(100)
hours decimal(10,0)
staff_id(INT 11)
```

my query looks like:

```
    SELECT
        timesheet.staff_id,
        task.assigned_to,
        SUM(task.hrs) AS assigned_hrs,
        timesheet.name,
        SUM(timesheet.hours) AS actual_hours
    FROM timesheet
    INNER JOIN task
    ON timesheet.staff_id = task.assigned_to
    GROUP BY timesheet.name
```

which will (incorrectly) result in:

```
staff_id       |assigned_to |assigned_hrs    | name.         |  actual_hours |
---------------|------------|----------------|---------------|---------------|
4              |4           | 1364           | John Smith    |52          
2              |2           | 80             | Jane Doe      |14.5        
6              |6           | 454            | Test User 1   |40          
9              |9           | 262            | Test User 2   |4
```

The above is what I am trying to get, However
all of the results are correct but John Smith's assigned hours get doubled.
I know it has to do with the "Grouping Pitfall"
as described here:

http://wikido.isoftdata.com/index.php/The_GROUPing_pitfall

but I just go cross eyed trying to figure this out.
can someone point me in the right direction?

(edit again)
        If I run a query just on the task table:

```
    SELECT
    task.assigned_to,
    SUM(task.hrs) AS allocated_hrs
    FROM task
    GROUP BY task.assigned_to
```

It (correctly) results in:

```
assigned_to | allocated_hrs |
----------------------------
4           |    682
7           |    378
2           |    40
6           |    227
9           |    262
```

you can see that the user ID of "4" which is John Smith has doubled (and also ID 6)

running a query on just the timesheet table :

```
    SELECT
    timesheet.name,
    SUM(timesheet.hours) AS actual_hours
    FROM timesheet
    GROUP BY timesheet.name
```

correctly results in :

```
    name    |  Actual_hrs
    -------------------------
    Jane Doe   | 19.5
    John Smith | 6.5
    Test User1 | 4
    Test User2 | 5
```

running the query supplied by JoachimL results in :

```
    staff_id |  assigned_to |   assigned_hrs |  name |  actual_hours
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    2   2   40  Jane Doe    19.5
    4   4   24  John Smith  6.5
    4   4   7   John Smith  6.5
    4   4   21  John Smith  6.5
    4   4   210 John Smith  6.5
    4   4   28  John Smith  6.5
    4   4   91  John Smith  6.5
    6   6   14  Test User 1 8
    6   6   91  Test User 1 8
    6   6   28  Test User 1 8
    6   6   3   Test User 1 8
    9   9   24  Test User 2 1
    9   9   91  Test User 2 1
    9   9   56  Test User 2 1
```

Here's a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef680

Comment: Please edit your query to include the data that generates the incorrect results.

Comment: How about you GROUP BY timesheet.staff_id? Perhaps there are two John Smith's?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Also show sample data from timesheet table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , SUM(y.hrs) n
  FROM
     ( SELECT t.staff_id
            , t.name
            , SUM(t.hours) actual_hours
         FROM timesheet t
        GROUP 
           BY t.staff_id
     ) x
  JOIN task y
    ON y.assigned_to = x.staff_id
 GROUP
    BY staff_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef680/14

Comment: Brilliant! 
Thank you so much!
I have been strugging with this for days now, I am going to analyze your most ingenious query and learn from a master :)
have a wonderful weekend
cheers
Martin

Comment: Thank you *all* for the suggestions  and solutions, it is greatly appreciated. This is the first time I have used this site and I am so impressed with the vast knowledge here!

Answer (score 0):

No comment privs...

Does ID 4 and 6 have two rows in timesheet? The others just one? Then task.hrs would be doubled.

Something like this should avoid that.
If task_id is unique you don't have to sum that.
 (test data would help)

EDIT

```
SELECT
        ts.staff_id,
        task.assigned_to,
        task.hrs AS assigned_hrs,
        ts.name,
        ts.actual_hours
    FROM task
    INNER JOIN (SELECT staff_id, name, SUM(hours) as actual_hours FROM timesheet GROUP BY staff_id, name) as ts
    ON ts.staff_id = task.assigned_to
```

The above: group timesheet by staff_id/name 
Then join with tasks, which should be just one row per task

Comment: yes the timesheet table will hold multiple entries of the same user who will input actual time for each day.

Comment: The table design seems suspect. Can a user not work on two tasks? If that's the case an entry in timesheet will count towards both tasks.I think you need to join on two field, at least.

Comment: yes the user may have many hours assigned to him as different tasks. 
then he will input his actual hours for each task.
this is why I need to compare the two

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
        timesheet.staff_id,
        task.assigned_to,
        SUM(task.hrs) AS assigned_hrs,
        timesheet.name,
        SUM(timesheet.hours) AS actual_hours
    FROM task
    LEFT JOIN timesheet ON timesheet.staff_id = task.assigned_to
    GROUP BY timesheet.staff_id
```

Try a LEFT JOIN and make sure you group by a UNIQUE field. "name" may not be unique.

Note: the LEFT JOIN will leave out any timesheets that are not assigned to a task. You can reverse this by SELECT FROM timesheet LEFT JOIN task instead.

Edit: See this answer: [Select multiple sums with MySQL query and display them in separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418842/select-multiple-sums-with-mysql-query-and-display-them-in-separate-columns)

Sorry, no comment privileges yet.

Comment: this results in the same as the first result which doubles the allocated_hrs.