# mysql query "GROUP BY" giving random results

Tags: mysql

I was here once before and was assisted tremendously:
[mysql group by returning incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299362/mysql-group-by-returning-incorrect-result)

I am now stuck with a similar Query which has an added table:
here is the Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fe40/5

There are 3 tables: Project, Task and Timesheet
The Task table has a foreign key (project_id) which links back to the Parent Project, it also holds a value for "assigned hours".
The timesheet table holds the "actual_hours" and the users name.

what I am trying to do is SUM how many actual hours have been spent on each project.
this query returns incorrect and random results:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
`timesheet`.`name`,
SUM(`timesheet`.`hours`) AS `total_hours`,
`project`.`project_name`,
`task`.`task_name`,
 SUM(`task`.`hrs`) AS `assigned_hours`
 FROM
`task`
 INNER JOIN `project` ON (`task`.`project_id` = `project`.`project_id`)
 INNER JOIN `timesheet` ON (`task`.`task_id` = `timesheet`.`task_id`)
 GROUP BY
 `project`.`project_name`
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The fiddle is giving the same results every time... what is different for you?

Comment: Hm, I thought we kind of covered this last time :-(

Comment: Strawberry! yes we did and I have been wracking brain over this one with three tables, I have tried to modify your solution to this one and cannot figure out how to add the Project table in the query and pull out the Project -> Task -> hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the sum for the projects, why are you including the tasks?

```
SELECT SUM(ts.`hours`) AS `total_hours`,
       p.`project_name`,
       SUM(t.`hrs`) AS `assigned_hours`
FROM `task` t INNER JOIN
      `project` p
       ON t.`project_id` = p.`project_id`) INNER JOIN
       `timesheet` ts
       ON t.`task_id` = ts.`task_id`
GROUP BY p.`project_name`;
```

I have a feeling though that this might give inaccurate results because there may be multiple timesheet records for each task.  So you can try:

```
SELECT SUM(ts.total_hours) AS `total_hours`,
       p.`project_name`,
       SUM(t.`hrs`) AS `assigned_hours`
FROM `task` t INNER JOIN
      `project` p
       ON t.`project_id` = p.`project_id` INNER JOIN
       (select ts.task_id, sum(ts.hours) as total_hours
        from `timesheet` ts
        group by ts.task_id
       ) ts
       ON t.`task_id` = ts.`task_id`
GROUP BY p.`project_name`;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dc8ba/21) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I tried running this and it gave multiple errors that I was not sure what to do with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dc8ba/1
try it in the fiddle?

Comment: also the projects have no hours only tasks which contain assigned hours. The timesheet contain the actual hours. 
The way it works is a task is created under a project and so much time is allocated for that task and assigned to a staff member who then chips away at the allocated hours by performing actual hours worked and recording that in a time sheet.

Comment: Yes, that's it!
Thank you Gordon,
I was playing with your solution earlier and after removing a errant parenthesis it produced the correct results.
Thanks for confirming with your own fiddle :)
Awesome..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has support for non-standard grouping. The fix is to **group by all non-aggregate selected columns**:

```
...
GROUP BY `timesheet`.`name`, `project`.`project`, `task`.`task_name`
```

You should also remove the `DISTINCT` keyword.

In mysql *only* (all other databases will raise an exception), grouping by fewer than all non-aggregated columns results in a random row for each unique combination of those columns that are grouped by (although in practice, it isn't a random row but the first row encountered - YMMV is you rely on this).

Comment: Now this seems to work:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dc8ba/1
however I need to group it by project otherwise the project gets listed multiple times and when I generate a Google Pie chart from it, its overwhelming with pie slices!

Comment: I am dynamically pumping the query results into a google pie chart.
here is what it's coming out like:
[Pie Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/lookfar/MLTf4/)

Comment: No problem: remove `timesheet.name` from both the select and group-by clauses. Or if that's not enough, or you need time sheet name, similarly remove `task.task_name`

Comment: oh cool, that works also!
Thank you guys so much..wish I could buy you a cold beer, I think this stuff is finally starting to sink in :)

Comment: No worries. Although you now have enough reputation to vote, I notice you havent upvoted any answers. if an answer is "helpful", upvote it (by clicking the "up" triangle above the answer score to the left.