# I need this ? 3 querys?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, sum

I want to show visits ,in current day, last day and current day visits.
would you have another way of doing this?
or how to show multiple sums in a single query?
My code

```
$dataAtual = date('Y-m-d');
$diaAnterior = gmdate('d', time()-(3600*27));
$diaAnterior = date('Y-m-'.$diaAnterior);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DBSA.';charset=utf8', USER, PASS);
/*Query for sum current day*/
foreach($db->query("SELECT id,data,visita,titulo, SUM(visita) as quantity FROM visitas_single WHERE data = '$dataAtual'") as $diaAtual) ;
echo '<h3>Paginas Visitadas no dia '.date('d-M').' - Total ' . $diaAtual["quantity"].'</h3>';

/*Query for sum last day*/
foreach($db->query("SELECT id,data, visita, SUM(visita) as quan FROM visitas_single WHERE data = '$diaAnterior'") as $mostraAnterior);
echo '<h4>Anterior( '.$diaAnterior.') - Total ' . $mostraAnterior["quan"].'</h4>';

/*Query for show visited posts*/
echo '<h3>Pages Visitadas Hoje</h3>';
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM visitas_single WHERE data = '$dataAtual'") as $mostraAnterior){
    echo $mostraAnterior['id'].'.........';
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418842/select-multiple-sums-with-mysql-query-and-display-them-in-separate-columns

Comment: `$db->query("SELECT id,data,titulo,SUM(CASE WHEN data = '".$dataAtual."' THEN visita END) as currentvisit,SUM(CASE WHEN data = '".$diaAnterior."' THEN visita END) as anteriorvisit FROM visitas_single");`